# Hi i am new in Angular js can anyone tell me please what is $scope in Angular Js?? what its exactly do ??

Tags: angularjs

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCntlr">
Enter First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="frn" />
<br />
Enter First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lrn" />
<br />
Full name: {{FullName()}}<br />
</div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCntlr', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.frn ="Jitendra";
$scope.lrn = "Rajput";
$scope.FullName = function () {
return $scope.frn + " " + $scope.lrn;
}  
}]);
</script>
</body>
```

  -

---

Here i am writing a function to display full name dynamicaly.Its working fine     but i am not able to understand that what is the role of $scope??

---

Comment: Angular has one of the best documentation I have ever seen. Perhaps you should go to the trouble and read the basic information first?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` is the execution context for your expressions, objects and functions, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will invoke the controller with a $scope object.

In AngularJS, $scope is the application object (the owner of application variables and functions).

[for more:](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp)